# How to create a common interface function for implementations which require both common and specific parameters (in Python)?

Tags: python, interface, parameters, optional-parameters, modularity

Trying to write an interface function in Python that can be called on an an implementation while knowing the least amount of implementation-specific information about it as possible.  This is a little hard to explain in prose, so here comes a code example.

**Code:**

```
# This is the interface function.
def my_interface_function(obj, c1, c2, s1, s2):
    obj.fun(c1, c2, s1=s1, s2=s2)

class obj1(object):
    def fun(self, c1, c2, s1=None, s2=None):
        print c1, c2, s1

class obj2(object):
    def fun(self, c1, c2, s1=None, s2=None):
        print c1, c2, s2

# What I would like to happen is this:
my_interface_function(obj1(), 1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> 1, 2, 3

my_interface_function(obj2(), 1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> 1, 2, 4
```

**In summary:**

The idea here is that the param `s2` is not used (but declared) in obj1 - the same happens with `s1` in obj2.  If the param list grows for either of the implementing classes, the other classes' grow as well, even if most of them may not be used.

Using `**kwargs` in the interface is an option, but the main concern with that, at least in my perspective, is having to know too much about the underlying code to be a useful and extensible interface.  In other words, the question will then become how to determine which parameters to use to call the function.

What is a good way to write the interface and implementing functions to have a good, mod and readable code?

Thanks very much!

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you're getting at here.  What is the problem with your example?  Why are you going to need to keep adding new arguments to `my_interface_function`?  If you have multiple classes with similar-but-not-identical interfaces, and you allow people to use them via a shared interface like `my_interface_function`, that is going to be confusing no matter how you slice it, because `my_interface_function` is hiding genuine differences in the underlying methods.

Comment: Concretely, this is about indexing objects for different databases.  The methods to be used should be generic (a module should not know how to index an object, but it should be able to have it indexed or search for it).  Most of them have a common set of parameters, but some parameters are specific to the implementations.  The main problem with the example is that modifications to one of the indexing modules will implicate changes to others (since the signature must be the same in all implementations).  Kwargs might work better, but require more knowledge about the implementation.

Comment: In Python 3, keyword-only arguments might be a solution to this problem.  However, I still don't see what you mean about "requiring more knowledge of the implementation".  Whether you write them as positional or keyword, anyone using the function needs to know what arguments are available if they want to use them.

Comment: That is a very good point.  My concern was in requiring users of the function to know which parameter to pass in (`s1` vs `s2`), but there is probably no avoiding it.  The great advantage of `kwargs` versus other possible implementations is that every implementation can process the arguments it requires and others are not affected. Thanks, +1.

Comment: The whole concept of an interface function is that it presents a common interface to callers and implementations alike. It seems obvious that if that changes then both clients and implementers of said interface are likely going to have to be modified to accommodate the modified interface. The trick is to design an interface that accommodate the largest number of implementations possible without change, or at least very little.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's cleaner to use `**kwargs` in this case and write a [docstrings](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) in particular functions. For example:

```
def my_interface_function(obj, c1, c2, **kw):
    obj.fun(c1, c2, **kw)

class obj1(object):
    def fun(self, c1, c2, **kw):
        """fun(c1, c2, s1) -> None"""
        print c1, c2, kw.get('s1')

class obj2(object):
    def fun(self, c1, c2, **kw):
        """fun(c1, c2, s2) -> None"""
        print c1, c2, kw.get('s2')
```

Comment: Yep, I like this idea.  I don't love that it requires the callers to know which `kwargs` to send, but I don't think there's something cleaner.  I'd love to have more alternatives, though.

Answer (score 1):

A more object-oriented approach to determining which parameters to use to call the object's method is to let the object make the decision. The idiomatic way to handle generic calling sequences in Python is via`*args`and`**kwargs`containers. Do these two things might result in something like the following:

```
def my_interface_function(obj, *args, **kwargs):
    obj.interface_function(*args, **kwargs)

class Class1(object):
    def interface_function(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.fun(args[0], args[1], kwargs['s1'])
    def fun(self, c1, c2, s1):
        print c1, c2, s1

class Class2(object):
    def interface_function(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.fun(args[0], args[1], kwargs['s2'])
    def fun(self, c1, c2, s2):
        print c1, c2, s2

my_interface_function(Class1(), 1, 2, s1=3, s2=4)  # -> 1, 2, 3
my_interface_function(Class2(), 1, 2, s1=3, s2=4)  # -> 1, 2, 4
```

From the preceding iyou can see that not much is being gained by having a separate interface function except the overhead of an extra function call, since you could have just as easily done the following instead:

```
Class1().interface_function(1, 2, s1=3, s2=4)  # -> 1, 2, 3
Class2().interface_function(1, 2, s1=3, s2=4)  # -> 1, 2, 4
```

This approach would reduce, and sometimes eliminate, the need to modify all the other interface functions when modifying an existing one or adding another depending on the nature of the changes — which is likely the best that be can done with respect to preventing an API change from affecting the rest of your existing implementation.

Comment: Interesting.  I am a bit concerned, as with the previous answer, that modifications in the interface function for a single class or type requires modifications in others as well.  Thanks for your input.